# Graph Theory, null pointer when trying to count nodes in tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tree

```
public class BuildTree {

    private HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> tree;
    private int edges;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BuildTree bt = new BuildTree();
        bt.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int treeRoot = 0;
        tree = new HashMap<>();
        edges = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int adjacent = in.nextInt();
            int root = in.nextInt();
            if (i == 0) {
                treeRoot = root;
            }
            if (!tree.containsKey(root)) {
                tree.put(root, new LinkedList<>());
                tree.get(root).add(adjacent);
            } else {
                tree.get(root).add(adjacent);
            }
        }

//        tree is built correctly
//        tree.get(1).forEach(System.out::print);
//        System.out.println();
//        tree.get(2).forEach(System.out::print);
//        System.out.println();
//        tree.get(3).forEach(System.out::print);
//        System.out.println();
//        tree.get(6).forEach(System.out::print);
//        System.out.println();
//        tree.get(8).forEach(System.out::print);

        System.out.println(treeSize(2)); //expecting 3
    }

    private int treeSize(Integer i) {
        int size = 1;
        if (tree.get(i).isEmpty() || tree.get(i) == null) { //throws null pointer exception
            return size;
        } else {
            Iterator<Integer> it = tree.get(i).iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Integer subRoot = it.next();
                size += treeSize(subRoot); //issue flagged here by console, directs to problematic if statement above
            }
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

The console input is the following:
10 9
2 1
3 1
4 3
5 2
6 1
7 2
8 6
9 8
10 8

I have already checked that the tree is built correctly by printing the LinkedList of adjacent integers for each node. My method for calculating tree size in reference to a certain root node keeps throwing a null pointer exception. I'm a novice regarding graph theory, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You should *first* check that `tree.get(i)` is null, and only if it isn't, check if it is empty. That is, reverse the conditions in your `||`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, thanks! I came to the same discovery a few seconds before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right, but there is another solution of the problem

```
if (tree.get(i).isEmpty() || tree.get(i) == null)
```

Throws `NullPointerException`, but the conditions are in wrong order, if you do:

```
if (tree.get(i) == null || tree.get(i).isEmpty())
```

There will be no `NullPointerException`
**Why:** because conditions are checked from left to right, and when `tree.get(1) == null`, then it is **true**, so it will be:

```
if (true || tree.get(i).isEmpty())
```

Compiler doesnt solve the second part because it has to be true:

```
true || something || something_else = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem. It was a simple mistake on my part. I needed to remove the tree.get(i).isEmpty() from the if statement. Sorry for the trouble.